# Push notifications (GCM) permission at runtime?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-permissions

I have read that it is necessary to ask the user for some permissions at runtime for API 23 and up. For example: `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.
Is it necessary (or even possible) to ask for a runtime permission for using GCM/push notifications at runtime if API is 23 or higher?

I have tried using the `requestPermissions` method at runtime, but it doesn't seem to work (nothing happens) when I use it with any GCM/push notification related permissions.

I have the following permissions in my Manifest for this purpose:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

The only permission that the user knows of, is the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` when downloading the app from Play Store. Shouldn't the user be able to choose whether or not they would allow push notifications?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Actually the **Push Notification** permission lie in **Normal Category Permission** like INTERNET permission not in **Dangerous Category Permission**.

You **don't** have to ask for **Push Notification** permissions.

While Contacts/Locations are the Dangerous permissions because you are accessing user data.so always needed to ask to user to allow it.

Hope so you understand.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Comment: @Umer what is the name of permission in the "Normal Category" that enables Push Notifications?

Comment: You can receive Push Notifications , if you have Internet permission , Connected Internet and properly GCM Configuration .

Comment: That is a signature permission, and signature permissions are not part of the runtime permission system. They are granted automatically based upon signature matches.

Comment: So as its not a requirement to get permission by prompt, would it still be useful and user friendly to provide a prompt ... some how in react native? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY

Comment: Is this still true in 2019? Doesn't seem to me.

Comment: @LukasPoustka API 32 is part of Android 12. I assume you meant Tiramisu respectively API level 33, right?

Comment: @alexanderdavide: Of course! Android 13 (API 33) introduces a new way similar to iOS - a permission is necessary to use push notifications: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/changes/notification-permission

Comment: @LukasPoustka do you know how to support older versions pre 13 while implementing the new 13 sdk version?

Comment: @Eenvincible If your targetSdk equals 33, notifications are by default still allowed for Android 12L and lower. Any extra steps necessary.