# Get Notification access from Ionic2 App

Tags: android, cordova, angular, ionic2

Is there a way to get access to native android notifications from Ionic App by asking for Notification Access Permission?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294076/push-notifications-gcm-permission-at-runtime

Comment: But how can I get the permission from Ionic Application?

Comment: Did you read the answer? Especially this part : `You don't have to ask for Push Notification permissions`

Comment: That's all fine. But, I want to access all the notification from Ionic app. We can do this in Android.

Comment: Only giving permission will not work. Did you write some code for this? For the push notification? Like using plugin phonegap-push-plugin? Where are you sending the notification from? GCM/FCM or some other client?