# Ask permission for push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, android-permissions

I'm working an application and I need to use push notification. I know that push notification are a normal permission so I can't ask it at run time. But I would insert in the permission when the user downloads and installs the application, and the notice that the application should send a push notification.

How can I do it? Do I have to insert something in the manifest?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294076/push-notifications-gcm-permission-at-runtime

Comment: You can replicate runtime behaviour by showing your own dialog and maintaining a `SharedPreference` to see if it granted or not..

Comment: Pushes and notifications 2 entirely different things on Android. It's unclear what you're asking about.

Answer (score 60):

**UPDATE 2022**

The way we request permissions on Android has changed drastically with Android 13. Please see other answers below that mention the same.

---

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294076/push-notifications-gcm-permission-at-runtime), **you don't need permissions for push notifications**.

> Actually the push notification permission lie in the normal category
> permission like ***Internet*** permission, not in dangerous category
> permission.
>
> You don't have to ask for push notification permissions.
>
> While Contacts/Locations are the dangerous permissions because you are
> accessing user data. So it is always needed to ask the user to allow it.
>
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Comment: It has changed. So now you must ask permission for notifications on Android 13+. 
There is a new API for that:  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/changes/notification-permission

Comment: You can install the app without permission, but if you don't ask for permission, by default, notifications will not be displayed.

Comment: For android 12L and lower, what if one turns off the Post Notification permission, is it possible for the App to ask to re-enable it?

Answer (score 44):

Here's the answer to new update:
In API 33 we need runtime permission for push notification:
Full documentation is available [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/changes/notification-permission) but you can simply use like below :

in app level:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

you can trigger the prompt using this:

```
pushNotificationPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
```

handle notification result:

```
private val pushNotificationPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(RequestPermission()) { granted ->
            viewModel.inputs.onTurnOnNotificationsClicked(granted)
        }
```

Comment: Can I customize the text of this permission in the pop up dialogue?

Comment: As answered below, you do not need this permission at all for normal "background service" push notifications (ones for when the app is running on the device). You only POST_NOTIFICATIONS if attempting to send a notification while the app is not running.

Answer (score 34):

Here is the complete example of how can you ask run time permission for notifications in Android 13 (Tiramisu)

First, add the below permission in your `manifest` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

Use the below code to ask for run time permission

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.graphics.Color
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val notificationPermissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted ->
            hasNotificationPermissionGranted = isGranted
            if (!isGranted) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)) {
                            showNotificationPermissionRationale()
                        } else {
                            showSettingDialog()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "notification permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        }

    private fun showSettingDialog() {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, com.google.android.material.R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_Material3)
            .setTitle("Notification Permission")
            .setMessage("Notification permission is required, Please allow notification permission from setting")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok") { _, _ ->
                val intent = Intent(ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
                intent.data = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .show()
    }

    private fun showNotificationPermissionRationale() {

        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, com.google.android.material.R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_Material3)
            .setTitle("Alert")
            .setMessage("Notification permission is required, to show notification")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok") { _, _ ->
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
                    notificationPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
                }
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .show()
    }

    var hasNotificationPermissionGranted = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnRequestPermission).setOnClickListener {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
                notificationPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
            } else {
                hasNotificationPermissionGranted = true
            }
        }
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnShowNotification).setOnClickListener {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                showNotification()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showNotification() {

        val channelId = "12345"
        val description = "Test Notification"

        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel =
                NotificationChannel(channelId, description, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.BLUE

            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

        }

        val  builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setContentTitle("Hello World")
            .setContentText("Test Notification")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setLargeIcon(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    this.resources, R.drawable
                        .ic_launcher_background
                )
            )
        notificationManager.notify(12345, builder.build())
    }
}
```

> **If you using jetpack compose then user below code**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

  @RequiresApi(VERSION_CODES.M)
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
      JetpackComposeNotifcationPermissionTheme {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val permissionOpenDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        val rationalPermissionOpenDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

        if (permissionOpenDialog.value) {
          ShowSettingDialog(openDialog = permissionOpenDialog)
        }

        var hasNotificationPermission by remember {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            mutableStateOf(
              ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
              ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            )
          } else mutableStateOf(true)
        }

        val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
          contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
          onResult = { isGranted ->
            if (!isGranted) {
              if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)) {
                rationalPermissionOpenDialog.value = true
              } else {
                permissionOpenDialog.value = true
              }
            } else {
              hasNotificationPermission = isGranted
            }
          }
        )
        if (rationalPermissionOpenDialog.value) {
          ShowRationalPermissionDialog(openDialog = rationalPermissionOpenDialog) {
            rationalPermissionOpenDialog.value = false
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
              launcher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
            }
          }
        }


        Column(
          modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
          verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
          horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
          Button(onClick = {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
              launcher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
            }
          }) {
            Text(text = "Request permission")
          }
          Button(onClick = {
            if (hasNotificationPermission) {
              showNotification()
            }
          }) {
            Text(text = "Show notification")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private fun showNotification() {
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val channelId = "12345"
    val description = "Test Notification"

    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.O) {
      val notificationChannel =
        NotificationChannel(channelId, description, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
      notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.BLUE

      notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
      notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    }
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, channelId)
      .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
      .setContentTitle("Hello Nilesh")
      .setContentText("Test Notification")
      .build()
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification)
  }

  @Composable
  fun ShowSettingDialog(openDialog: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    if (openDialog.value) {
      AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = {
          openDialog.value = false
        },
        title = {
          Text(text = "Notification Permission")
        },
        text = {
          Text("Notification permission is required, Please allow notification permission from setting")
        },

        buttons = {
          Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
          ) {
            TextButton(
              onClick = {
                openDialog.value = false
              }
            ) {
              Text("Cancel")
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(20.dp))
            TextButton(
              onClick = {
                openDialog.value = false
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
                intent.data = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
                startActivity(intent)
              },
            ) {
              Text("Ok")
            }
          }

        },
      )
    }
  }

  @Composable
  fun ShowRationalPermissionDialog(openDialog: MutableState<Boolean>, onclick: () -> Unit) {
    if (openDialog.value) {
      AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = {
          openDialog.value = false
        },
        title = {
          Text(text = "Alert")
        },
        text = {
          Text("Notification permission is required, to show notification")
        },

        buttons = {
          Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
          ) {
            TextButton(
              onClick = {
                openDialog.value = false
              }
            ) {
              Text("Cancel")
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(20.dp))
            TextButton(
              onClick = onclick,
            ) {
              Text("Ok")
            }
          }

        },
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Android 13 permission push notification dialog is popping up itself without asking any permission in menifest. Do we still need to request runtime permission.

Comment: @waheedshah If targetSdk 33 you have to integrate run time permission and if targetSdk 32 or lower automatically app will ask for the permission.

Comment: What should happen if the user clicks "Skip" in the sample screens : https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission#wait-to-show-prompt ? Will shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale return next time true again and the user will see this rationale page again?

Comment: Thank you for this. I have been trying to come up with a way to cleanly ask for this based on the official docs but been having a lot of issues with compose and trying to figure out if I needed to launch a whole new composable screen, or what. This was extremely helpful!!!

Answer (score 14):

If your app targets Android 13 (Tiramisu) or higher, you must declare the [POST_NOTIFICATIONS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#POST_NOTIFICATIONS) permission as follows:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

For more details, see the [Notification runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission) page in the Android Developers documentation.

Comment: API 32 is part of Android 12. I assume you meant Tiramisu respectively API level 33, right?

Comment: Yep you are right, API 32 refers to Android 12L. I'm fixing the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

```
 int permissionState = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);
    // If the permission is not granted, request it.
    if (permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>// add this to menifest file

 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        
            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, 1);

    } 
    else {
      // repeat the permission or open app details
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions

```
import {requestNotifications} from 'react-native-permissions';

await requestNotifications(['alert', 'badge', 'sound']);
```

and add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

to androidManifest.xml

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

In your Activity class, add the below code:

```
private static final int NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);

    requestNotificationPermission();

    // Some code
}

 private void requestNotificationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY)) {

    }

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY}, NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION_CODE );
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    // Checking the request code of our request
    if (requestCode == NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION_CODE ) {

        // If permission is granted
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Displaying a toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```