# How to implement `AppCompatActivity` in a Flutter plugin?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm trying to create a Flutter plugin that asks for user notification permission. Most of the suggestion on this thread [Ask permission for push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305206/ask-permission-for-push-notification) suggest to do something like:

```kotlin
private val pushNotificationPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(RequestPermission()) { granted ->
            viewModel.inputs.onTurnOnNotificationsClicked(granted)
        }
```

But to use `registerForActivityResult` function, the class must be a subclass of `AppCompatActivity` as far as I understood, and my plugin implementation is a subclass of `FlutterPlugin`. The question is, how to use `registerForActivityResult` in a Flutter Android plugin? Should I create a separate `Activity` to subclass `AppCompatActivity`? And if so, how to create that and integrate with the Flutter plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After studying more about Android environment I ended up with a simple solution. To invoke UI elements in a Flutter Android plugin, we just need to invoke an `AppCompatActivity` using an Intent. Using the push notification example above (but you can change to whenever permission you want to present), we need to create an `AppCompatActivity` subclass and write the proper code to ask for the permission:

```kotlin
class PushPermissionActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { 
        isGranted: Boolean -> 
        if (isGranted) {
            sendBroadcast(Intent(ACTION_PERMISSIONS_GRANTED))
        } else {
            sendBroadcast(Intent(ACTION_PERMISSIONS_DENIED))
        }
        finish()
    }

        return requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
    }
}
```

After that, register this new activity in the `AndroidManifest`:

```xml
<activity android:name="PushPermissionActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
```

After that, you can invoke the activity using an `Intent` in the plugin implementation file:

```kotlin
private fun requestPermission(result: Result) {
    val permissionReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
      init {
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_PERMISSIONS_GRANTED)
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_PERMISSIONS_DENIED)
        context.registerReceiver(this, intentFilter)
      }

            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                when {
                intent.action == ACTION_PERMISSIONS_GRANTED -> {
                    result.success(2)
                    context.unregisterReceiver(this)
                }
                intent.action == ACTION_PERMISSIONS_DENIED -> {
                    result.success(1)
                    context.unregisterReceiver(this)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
      val intent = Intent(context, PushPermissionActivity::class.java)
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      this.context.startActivity(intent)
  }
```

Comment: Many thanks for sharing this solution ❤ You've helped out a lot!