# How can i check push notification permission for both ios and android in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I want to check push notification permission for both ios and android. I want to see if user has switched off the push notification permission from his device settings. Is there any plugin or any code i can take reference from if needed to be coded in native.

Answer (score 5):

You can check [react-native-permissions](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions) [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions). After integrating you can use it like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  Permissions.check('notification').then(response => {
    // Response is one of: 'authorized', 'denied', 'restricted', or 'undetermined'
    this.setState({ photoPermission: response })
  })
}
```

There is [another library](https://github.com/Eaffy/react-native-android-notification-permission) that can help (I have not used it).

There is also native implementation for as suggested [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios).

Comment: but 'notification' permission using react-native-permission only works with ios and not with android.

Comment: That is why added "another library".

Comment: As of today, the "react-native-permissions" describes itself as "A unified permissions API for React Native on iOS, Android and Windows.", so maybe they updated it =)

Answer (score 4):

Official way https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions#checknotifications

```js
import {requestNotifications} from 'react-native-permissions';

requestNotifications(['alert', 'sound']).then(({status, settings}) => {
  // …
});
```

Comment: only available on iOS

Answer (score -1):

**Android:**

Actually the Push Notification permission lie in Normal Category Permission like INTERNET permission not in Dangerous Category Permission.

*You don't have to ask for Push Notification permissions.*

More details is here,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37294287/7188778

Comment: This has changed since Android 13: https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/notification-perm

Answer (score -1):

You can use **[Notifee Library](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/android/permissions)** package to request for notification permission for both (ios and android) and also you can check the permission status but i don't think there is a package which states whether permission is switched off by user.