# Check if user has push notification turned on

Tags: laravel, push-notification, onesignal

I need some help. We have an app build with React Native that communicates with API that is build on Laravel. For push notifications we used One Signal. It works great, no problems there. The only issue we have is how can we know if user has push notifications enabled for our app? Is there any way that through One Signal we can check this one out?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

found this post similar to:
[How can i check push notification permission for both ios and android in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371380/how-can-i-check-push-notification-permission-for-both-ios-and-android-in-react-n)

get the permission status then update to server using api from laravel.