# Do anyone know how to access notification permission from special app access?

Tags: react-native

I am building an android app and I want to access notification permission from special app access. I am not getting any way to do it. Is there anyone know about this thing?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294076/push-notifications-gcm-permission-at-runtime) **you don't need permissions for push notifications**.

> Actually the push notification permission lie in the normal category
> permission like Internet permission, not in dangerous category
> permission.
>
> You don't have to ask for push notification permissions.
>
> While Contacts/Locations are the dangerous permissions because you are
> accessing user data. So it is always needed to ask the user to allow
> it.
>
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

If want to request and check notification status, then i would recommend you to try this https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions#checknotifications

```js
import {requestNotifications} from 'react-native-permissions';

requestNotifications(['alert', 'sound']).then(({status, settings}) => {
  // …
});
```

Comment: This answer entirely unrelatable to the question. Try to understand the question before answering